# Redirects after permalink change

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I am using the permalink settings `/%category%/%post_id%/`.

And all URLs are indexed by Google using the above.

Now I want to change the permalink to `/%postname%/`.

But this will make all Google search results going to the 404 page. How can I redirect old URLss to the new ones?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your server. If you're on an Apache server, you could use the .htaccess file. If you're on NGINX, there is a .conf file. Your web host may (or may not) be able to help you with this.

Or, you could use a plugin. There are many redirection plugins available - you may want to try one out on a staging site to see how well it works, and use an HTTP Header Check (there are free ones online, where you paste in a URL and it tells you what response the server gave - such as 404, 301, 200) to verify that they're returning the headers you want them to, then copy everything over to the live site.

Comment: Hi and thank you for reply,
My server based on Apache, but the problem i am not good with coding and .htaccess file.
So i tried this plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ , 
and the setting page set like this https://imgur.com/OEuae3n but no redirect, the old URls send me to 404 page, any advice please ?

Comment: If you're having problems with a specific plugin it's usually best to ask the plugin developer. Sometimes your hosting company can also provide support.